Rust with MongoDB sort by date latest
Here, I am using MongoDB to get the collections:
let filter = doc! {};
let mut cursor = match collection.find(filter).await {
    Ok(cursor) => cursor,
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("Error querying MongoDB: {}", e);
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body("Error querying MongoDB");
    }
};

I would like to add a short by createdAt column base:
let sort = doc! { "createdAt ": -1 };

Please give a solution.

In the mongodb v3.0 crate, many commands use a builder pattern for additional options. You'll see that .find() returns a Find type which includes additional methods you can call before .await-ing the result. In this case you can simply use the .sort() method:
let filter = doc! {};
let sort = doc! { "createdAt ": -1 };
let mut cursor = match collection.find(filter).sort(sort).await {
    ...                                    // ^^^^^^^^^^^
};

